# Sorting PowerShell versions

Tags: sorting, powershell

In PowerShell, if I have a list of strings containing versions, "3.0.1.1", "3.2.1.1", etc., how can I sort it the way System.Version would sort it in C#?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
PS C:\> $ver="3.0.1.1","3.2.1.1"
PS C:\> $ver|%{[System.Version]$_}|sort

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      1      1
3      2      1      1
```

Answer (score 12):

Just convert it to a Version and sort that way:

```
$list = "3.0.1.1","3.2.1.1" 
$sorted = $list | %{ new-object System.Version ($_) } | sort
```

Answer (score 7):

A version string can be cast to a Version object, and
`sort-object` can be passed a script block and sort on the result.

```
PS C:\Users\me> "3.11.0.1", "3.0.1.1", "3.2.1.1" | sort
3.0.1.1
3.11.0.1
3.2.1.1

PS C:\Users\me> "3.11.0.1", "3.0.1.1", "3.2.1.1" | sort {[version] $_}
3.0.1.1
3.2.1.1
3.11.0.1
```

(Added an extra version string to make the example actually meaningful.)

Answer (score 2):

```
# I needed to sort historical versions (Octopus) with varying decimal formats.
# Try # this (it is easy to add to a more complex expression sort)
# Special Case "3.00.1.10.1.10" and "3.0.1.10.1.10" required the double sort
# to work correctly
    $vers = @()`enter code here`
    $vers +=  @( "3.1.60",      "3.1.52","3.1.51")
    $vers +=  @( "3.00.46",     "3.00.36","3.50.2145.11")
    $vers +=  @( "3.50.2145.10","3.50.2145.9")
    $vers +=  @( "3.50.2145.8", "3.50.2145.7")
    $vers +=  @( "3.50.2145.6", "3.50.2145.5")
    $vers +=  @( "3.50.2145.4", "3.50.2145.3")
    $vers +=  @( "3.50.2145.2", "3.50.2145.1")
    $vers +=  @( "3.50.2145",   "3.50.2143")
    $vers +=  @( "3.50.2141",    "3.50.2135")    
    $vers +=  @( "3.0.1.10.1.1", "3.00.1.10.1.10")
    $vers +=  @( "2.1.3.4",      "3.0","3.")
    $vers +=  @( "3.0.1.10.1.100","3.0.1.10.1.10")
    $mySortAsc = @{Expression={ [regex]::Replace($_ ,'\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20,'0') }) };Descending=$false}
    $mySortDesc = @{Expression={ [regex]::Replace($_ ,'\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20,'0') }) };Descending=$true}    
    $nl = [Environment]::NewLine
    Write-Output ($nl + "Ascending Sort" + $nl);
    $vers | Sort-Object | Sort-Object $mySortAsc
    Write-Output ($nl + "Descending Sort" + $nl);
    $vers | Sort-Object -Descending | Sort-Object $mySortDesc
<# Result
Ascending Sort

2.1.3.4
3.
3.0
3.0.1.10.1.1
3.0.1.10.1.10
3.00.1.10.1.10
3.0.1.10.1.100
3.00.36
3.00.46
3.1.51
3.1.52
3.1.60
3.50.2135
3.50.2141
3.50.2143
3.50.2145
3.50.2145.1
3.50.2145.2
3.50.2145.3
3.50.2145.4
3.50.2145.5
3.50.2145.6
3.50.2145.7
3.50.2145.8
3.50.2145.9
3.50.2145.10
3.50.2145.11

Descending Sort

3.50.2145.11
3.50.2145.10
3.50.2145.9
3.50.2145.8
3.50.2145.7
3.50.2145.6
3.50.2145.5
3.50.2145.4
3.50.2145.3
3.50.2145.2
3.50.2145.1
3.50.2145
3.50.2143
3.50.2141
3.50.2135
3.1.60
3.1.52
3.1.51
3.00.46
3.00.36
3.0.1.10.1.100
3.00.1.10.1.10
3.0.1.10.1.10
3.0.1.10.1.1
3.0
3.
2.1.3.4
#>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This works really well! I dont have proper System.Versions as my version names include a "V" before the numbers. The Regex does not seem to care about that. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another corner case: powershell treats this single digit kind of version '2' as invalid.
Have to add '.0' to the end to create the version object before sorting:

```
if($version  -match '^\d$')
{
  $version = $version + '.0'
}
New-Object System.Version $version
```

Comment: The .NET System.Version class declares version numbers consist of two to four components: major.minor[.build[.revision]].