# In a batch file ran from Windows, select latest application version using directory name

Tags: batch-file

I use a portable application that have updates quite often. The problem is that each version of the application has a folder named "processing-x.y.z". Each time I install a new version, I need to associate the files with the new version which is in a different folder. So to workaround this annoyance, I want to associate the "*.pde" file type to a batch file.

The folder names go as follow

- processing-3.2.1
- processing-3.2.2
- etc.

I have created this small batch script that get the executable from the latest version.

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir processing* /a:d /b /o-n') do (
  set currentFolder=%%~fD

  :: Check if environment variable already set
  if not %currentFolder%==%processing% (
    :: Set environment variable processing
    setx processing %currentFolder%
  )

  %currentFolder%/processing.exe %1
  goto :eof
)
```

It works when launching it from the command-line, but not within Windows. Is there a specific reason? Also, is there a way to optimize this code?

Thanks

Comment: 1. This approach works only as long as the version numbers are one digit each; as soon as you have e. g. `3.2.10`, sorting fails. 2. Since you are setting *and* reading variables within the same block of code, you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); alternatively, revert the sort order (`/on`) and keep `set currentFolder=%%~fD` as the only code within the `for /F` loop, then do all the rest outside of the loop...

Comment: @aschipfl - is this comment aimed for my answer?  :-D

Comment: @npocmaka, I guess you posted it while I was typing my comment, so no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the version numbers always consist of a single digit each, I would do it the following way:

```dos
@echo off

rem // Reset variable:
set "currentFolder="
rem /* Loop through the folders in ascending order, overwrite the variable
rem    in each iteration, so it holds the highest version finally: */
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /A:D /O:N "processing-*.*.*"') do (
    set "currentFolder=%%~fD"
)

rem // Check if environment variable is already set:
if not "%processing%"=="%currentFolder%" (
    rem // Set environment variable `processing`:
    setx processing "%currentFolder%"
)

rem // Execute `processing.exe`:
"%currentFolder%/processing.exe" "%~1"
```

---

If the individual version numbers can consist of more than one digit (four at most here), use this:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Assign each found folder to a variable called `$ARRAY_X_Y_Z`, where `X`, `Y`, `Z`
rem    are zero-padded variants of the original numbers `x`, `y`, `z`, so for instance,
rem    a folder called `processing-4.7.12` is stored in variable `$ARRAY_0004_0007_0012`: */
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=-. eol=." %%A in ('
    dir /B /A:D "processing-*.*.*" ^| ^
    findstr /R /I "^processing-[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*$"
') do (
    rem // Perform the left-side zero-padding here:
    set "MAJ=0000%%B" & set "MIN=0000%%C" & set "REV=0000%%D"
    set "$ARRAY_!MAJ:~-4!_!MIN:~-4!_!REV:~-4!=%%A-%%B.%%C.%%D"
)
rem // Reset variable:
set "currentFolder="
rem /* Loop through the output of `set "$ARRAY_"`, which returns all variables beginning
rem    with `$ARRAY_` in ascending alphabetic order; because of the zero-padding, where
rem    alphabetic and alpha-numeric orders become equivalent, the item with the greatest
rem    version number item is iterated lastly, therefore the latest version is returned: */
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%E in ('set "$ARRAY_"') do (
    set "currentFolder=%%F"
)
endlocal & set "currentFolder=%currentFolder%"

rem // The rest of the script os the same as above...
```

You can also find similar approaches here:

- [How to get latest version number using batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38738428) (this approach also relies on the sorting featurre of the `set` command)
- [How to sort lines of a text file containing version numbers in format major.minor.build.revision numerical?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418090) (this uses the `sort` command upon a temporary file or on piped (`|`) data)

Answer (score 0):

not tested (edited: should handle the cases when minor versions have more digits):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

    set /a latest_n1=0
    set /a latest_n2=0
    set /a latest_n3=0

for /f "tokens=2,3* delims=-." %%a in ('dir processing* /a:d /b /o-n') do (
    set "current_v=%%a.%%b.%%c"
    set /a "current_n1=%%a"
    set /a "current_n2=%%b"
    set /a "current_n3=%%c"

    if !current_n1! GTR !latest_n1! (

        set /a latest_n1=!current_n1!
        set /a latest_n2=!current_n2!
        set /a latest_n3=!current_n3!

        set "latest_v=!current_v!"
    ) else  if !current_n1! EQU !latest_n1! if !current_n2! GTR !latest_n2! (

        set /a latest_n1=!current_n1!
        set /a latest_n2=!current_n2!
        set /a latest_n3=!current_n3!

        set "latest_v=!current_v!"
    ) else if !current_n1! EQU !latest_n1! if !current_n2! EQU !latest_n2! if !current_n3! GTR !latest_n3! (

        set /a latest_n1=!current_n1!
        set /a latest_n2=!current_n2!
        set /a latest_n3=!current_n3!

        set "latest_v=!current_v!"
    )

)

echo latest version=processing-%latest_v%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir processing* /a:d /b /o-n') do (
 if "%processing%" neq "%cd%\%%F" setx processing "%cd%\%%F" >nul
 .\%%F\processing.exe %1
 goto :eof
)
```

is equivalent code - almost.

First problem - the `::` form of comments should not be used within a code block (parenthesised series of statements) as `::` is in fact a label that itself stars with a colon. Since it is a label, it terminates the block.

Next problem - within a code block, `%var% refers to the value of`var`**as it stood when the`for` was encountered** - not as it changes within the loop.

Next problem - as noted by others, `/o-n` produces a by-name sequence, so `10` is likely to sort *after* `9` (since the sort is reversed).  I've not changed this in the replacement code, but `/o-d` to sort by reverse-date may be better suited to your application.

Now to how your code works.

First, `processing` is set to whatever the last run established. If *that* is different from the value calculated from this run, then `setx` the new value. Bizarrely, `setx` does not `set` the value in the current `cmd` instance, only for instances created in the future.

You then attempt to execute your process and then exit the batch with the `goto :eof`. Only problem is that `%currentfolder%` is **not** the value as changed by the loop, because it's supposed to be in the code block. It *appears* to change because the `::-comments` have broken the block and where `currentfolder` is used in your code, it is *outside* of the block.

Instead, use `.\%%F\executablename` which means "from the current directoryname (`.`);subdirectory `%%F`;filenametoexecute" - note that "\" is a directory-separator in windows, '/' indicates a switch.