# How to get just a part of file version via CMD

Tags: batch-file

I need to get version of a file but then I need to use just a part of it in order to perform some further actions (e.g. compare it and continue according to the result).

Example:
File version is *17.5.834.0*, what I need to get and use is just the *834* number.

I use the following to get the number and work with it:

```
@echo off
if exist "c:\Program Files\myprg\myfile.exe" SET prgfolder=c:\Program Files\myprg
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name='%prgfolder:\=\\%\\myfile.exe' get Version /format:Textvaluelist"`) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"
)
echo %version%
if %version% gtr 17.5.3000.0 echo Hello World
```

The echo prints the whole number and when it is e.g. 17.5.834.0 then it does not work with the `if gtr 17.5.3000.0`. My idea was to extract just the third number and adjust the IF then. Thank you in advance for any tip.

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34417346/2152082)

Comment: It seems that for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%# in ("%%a") do set version=%%# does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vbscript to get file version .

Try my way :

```
@echo off
Rem Your file : 
Set "File=C:\Program Files\Windows Mail\wabmig.exe"

cd /d "%~dp0"
Echo Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")>>Q.vbs
Echo Wscript.Echo objFSO.GetFileVersion("%File%")>>Q.vbs
FOR /F %%A IN ('cscript //nologo Q.vbs') DO Set version=%%A
Del "Q.vbs"
echo %version%
if %version% gtr 17.5.3000.0 echo Hello World
```