# Sort alphanumerical string with trailing zeroes

Tags: powershell, sorting

I have a script that contains an array of alphanumerical strings like `VER11.10.00.000`, `VER11.10.01.123` and `VER9.09.02.050`.

I sort this array like this

```
[string[]] $HighestVER = $Version | Sort -Descending
foreach($element in $HighestVER) {
    Write-Host $element
}
```

`$Version` represents an un-ordered array of the strings.
When running the script the outcome looks like this:

```
VER9.16.00.000
VER9.15.00.000
VER9.14.00.000
VER9.13.00.000
VER11.9.00.000
VER11.8.00.000
VER11.7.00.000
VER11.6.00.000
VER11.5.00
VER11.4.00.000
VER11.3.00.016
VER11.3.00.000
VER11.2.00.000
VER11.10.00.000
```

As you can see the sort is doing something, but it doesn't do it as I expected. My expected output is:

```
VER11.10.00.000
VER11.9.00.000
VER11.8.00.000
VER11.7.00.000
VER11.6.00.000
VER11.5.00
VER11.4.00.000
VER11.3.00.016
VER11.3.00.000
VER11.2.00.000
VER9.16.00.000
VER9.15.00.000
VER9.14.00.000
VER9.13.00.000
```

How can I improve my code to match the expected output?

Edit:

I can't solve this problem with `[System.Version]` because I have the alphabetical chars in my version. If I remove the first three chars `VER` and do the comparison it kinda works, but the elemnts of the version get messed up.

```
[string[]] $HighestVER = $Version2 | ForEach-Object { [System.Version] $_ } | Sort-Object -Descending | ForEach-Object { $_.toString() }


#[string[]] $HighestVER = $Version | Sort -Descending
foreach($element in $HighestVER) {
    $element = "VER" + $element
    Write-Host $element
}
```

which gives me this output:

```
VER11.10.0.0
VER11.9.0.0
VER11.8.0.0
VER11.7.0.0
VER11.6.0.0
VER11.5.0
VER11.4.0.0
VER11.3.0.16
VER11.3.0.0
VER11.2.0.0
VER9.16.0.0
VER9.15.0.0
VER9.14.0.0
VER9.13.0.0
```

The highest version no. is used for comparison and extending the version list (Dynamics NAV automatic build). Because of that the format hast to be identical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting PowerShell versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711107/sorting-powershell-versions)

Comment: the `Sort-Object` cmdlet can use a _calculated sort_. that would let you sort on the trimmed version but still output the original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable `$vers` contains an array of versions in the format you provided, the following will work.

```
(($vers  -replace "VER(?<Num>.*)",'${Num}' |
  ForEach-Object {$_ -as [system.version]}) | Sort-Object -Desc) |
  Foreach-Object {
    ("VER{0}.{1}.{2:D2}.{3:D3}" -f $_.Major,$_.Minor,$_.Build,$_.Revision) -replace "\.-\d+"}
```

This solution basically extracts the version number and converts it to a `[system.version]` object. That object can be sorted naturally using `Sort-Object` in the manner you are asking. Once the sort is complete, the output is rebuilt converting those version objects to strings.

The `-replace` operator does a regex replace. The first removes string `VER` from each line. The second removes any negative integers added by the cast to `[system.version]`.

The last `Foreach-Object` is formatting the output with the format operator (`-f`) It adds back the string `VER` that was removed prior to sorting. Then it takes each part of the `[system.version]` object to perform a padded concatenation. `{2:D2}` pads the third numerical part of the version with leading 0s to make it a two-digit number. `{3:D3}` pads the fourth numerical part of the version with leading 0s to make it a three-digit number.

Upon further testing, using a comment from [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey), this can be shortened and made more efficient:

```
$vers | Sort-Object {$_ -replace "VER(?<Num>.*)",'${Num}' -as [system.version]} -desc
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `$ToNatural` from Roman Kuzmin which expands all numbers in a string to given places (20) on the fly:

```
## source Roman Kuzmin  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20,"0") }) }

$HighestVER = $Version | Sort -Descending $ToNatural
$HighestVER
```

---

```
VER11.10.00.000
VER11.9.00.000
VER11.8.00.000
VER11.7.00.000
VER11.6.00.000
VER11.5.00
VER11.4.00.000
VER11.3.00.016
VER11.3.00.000
VER11.2.00.000
VER9.16.00.000
VER9.15.00.000
VER9.14.00.000
VER9.13.00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'
VER9.16.00.000
VER9.15.00.000
VER9.14.00.000
VER9.13.00.000
VER11.9.00.000
VER11.8.00.000
VER11.7.00.000
VER11.6.00.000
VER11.5.00
VER11.4.00.000
VER11.3.00.016
VER11.3.00.000
VER11.2.00.000
VER11.10.00.000
' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header String |
    Select-Object String, 
        @{Name='Version';Expression={[System.Version]::New($_.String.SubString(3))}} |
    Sort-Object -Descending Version | 
    Select-Object -Expand String

VER11.10.00.000
VER11.9.00.000
VER11.8.00.000
VER11.7.00.000
VER11.6.00.000
VER11.5.00
VER11.4.00.000
VER11.3.00.016
VER11.3.00.000
VER11.2.00.000
VER9.16.00.000
VER9.15.00.000
VER9.14.00.000
VER9.13.00.000
```

### Explanation

- Create a single column object list with a `String` property
- Add a `Version` (type) column
- Sort the list based on the `Version` column
- Output only the ***original*** data in the `String` column

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script block with sort-object.  Kind of like another answer.

```
PS C:\users\me> $version | sort { [version]($_ -replace 'VER') } -Desc

VER11.10.00.000
VER11.9.00.000
VER11.8.00.000
VER11.7.00.000
VER11.6.00.000
VER11.5.00
VER11.4.00.000
VER11.3.00.016
VER11.3.00.000
VER11.2.00.000
VER9.16.00.000
VER9.15.00.000
VER9.14.00.000
VER9.13.00.000
```